# How to set the Security Q&A of Google Accounts?

Tags: google-account

I Deleted the Sercet Question when I checked my Google Account Security Settings. And Can't Restore it(to Set a new Security Question).Since I can't find the href to set this question.
Have Google Removed the Security Question?

[image: The Screen]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a support request.

Comment: I don't think so, Could you spend a minute to test in the  Google's Page?

Answer (score 3):

Have you look here ? [Sign-in & security](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security?hl=en#signin)

[image: Security Google]

### **EDIT**

Google has removed [Security Question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/no$20security$20question/gmail/aO_Aedbb0iE)

Comment: Yep, But I can't find the 'Security Question' option in the page. I think Google have removed this feature.

Comment: @tan9p - If i login i have this function, it's called **Secret Question** ... I edit my post with a screen

Comment: @tan9p - Google remove it. Look my post!

Comment: Thanks : ) and you can have the Sercet Question while I  have lost it forever ... what a pity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Click the gear icon at the top of any Gmail page and select Mail settings.
Click Accounts and Import.
Click Change password recovery options in the 'Change account settings'  section.
Click Edit under 'Security Question'.
Complete the form and click Save to make your changes
```

Comment: It doesn't work,The Change password recovery options leads me to a new page where there is now “Security Question”.